# My TraMineR sequence plot exceeds the set data range. Why does it do that and how can I fix it?

Tags: r, traminer

My problems can easily be summarized in these two pictures:

Sequence Plots: 
[image]

Sequence Frequency:

[image]

The x axis is exceeded, although the dataset ends at 2018. I really hope to find out why this is the case .

I tried limiting the time period by a year to end in 2017. No change. I am a bit of a noob though so my ideas were limited. My guess might be that it gets confused by the "NA" category. But the overall plot looks normal. It is only the cluster plots and the sequence frequency plot that goes beyond the x axis.

```
MyData <- read.csv2(file="e:/Dokumente (-videoedluxe)/IBP dokumente/Msc/seq/mappe1.csv", sep=";", skipNul=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na = "empty")

str(MyData, sep=",")

install.packages("TraMineR")
Yes
library("TraMineR")

table(data$x1989)

data.seq <-seqdef(MyData, var = 2:31, ext = TRUE, gaps="NA"
                  alphabet=c("GOVspec","GOVinv","GOVno","IOspec","IOinv","IOno","ICspec","ICinv","ICno","MNCspec","MNCinv","MNCno","NGOspec","NGOspec","NGOinv","NGOno","NPOspec","NPOinv","NPOno","UNIspec","UNIinv","UNIno","EDUspec","EDUinv","EDUno", NA),
                  states = c("GOVspec","GOVinv","GOVno","IOspec","IOinv","IOno","ICspec","ICinv","ICno","MNCspec","MNCinv","MNCno","NGOspec","NGOspec","NGOinv","NGOno","NPOspec","NPOinv","NPOno","UNIspec","UNIinv","UNIno","EDUspec","EDUinv","EDUno", NA)
cpal(data.seq) <-c("aquamarine2","aquamarine3","aquamarine4","chocolate2","chocolate3","chocolate4","cadetblue2","cadetblue3","cadetblue4","gold1","gold3","gold4","green2","green3","green4","hotpink2","hotpink3","hotpink4","orange2","orange3","orange4","purple2","purple4","rosybrown","orchid2", "white")
seqstatl(MyData)
summary(data.seq)

years = c(1989:2018)

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
seqdplot(data.seq, with.legend = FALSE, border = NA, x = years)
seqlegend(data.seq)

cost.constant <- seqsubm(data.seq, method="CONSTANT", time.varying= T, with.miss = FALSE)
cost.trate <- seqsubm(data.seq, method="TRATE", time.varying= T, with.miss = FALSE)

seqfplot(data.seq, withlegend="FALSE")
seqmtplot(data.seq, withlegend="RIGHT", title="Mean Time", 

analysis.manual <- seqdist(data.seq, method="OM", sm="TRATE", indel=1.5)
library(cluster)
analysis.manual = agnes(analysis.manual)
clusterward <- agnes(data.seq, method="ward")
plot(clusterward, which.plots = 2)

plot(analysis.trate, which.plots = 8)

## CLUSTER ANALYSIS

cluster1 = cutree(analysis.trate, 1)
cluster2 = cutree(analysis.trate, 2)
cluster3 = cutree(analysis.trate, 3)
cluster3 = cutree(analysis.trate, 4)

# Distribution plot
seqdplot(data.seq, group= cluster1, withlegend = F, border = NA, x = years)

# Index plots
seqIplot(data.seq, group= cluster1, withlegend = F, border = NA, x = years)
seqIplot(data.seq, group= cluster2, withlegend = F, border = NA, x = years)
seqIplot(data.seq, group= cluster3, withlegend = F, border = NA, x = years)
seqIplot(data.seq, group= cluster4, withlegend = F, border = NA, x = years)
```

I expect the plots to end when they should.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot reproduce the issue because we don't have the data. However, I observe that your alphabet contains twice the state `NGOspec`. Removing one of them and adapting conformably the `states` and `cpal` argument should solve the issue.